# Как на heroku выдать права доступа к файлу Node.js?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Приложение Node.js загружаю на heroku. Запускаю приложение (heroku open) и получаю ошибку:

```
MyApp@0.0.0 start /app
app/fileNode.js
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-112-generic 
sh: 1: app/fileNode.js: Permission denied
```

Загружаю и запускаю как описано в инструкции.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs
Из папки локального репозитория гит: git push heroku master
И затем запускаю: heroku open

Comment: Как вы его загружаете? Как запускаете?

Comment: Загружаю и запускаю, как по инструкции: git push heroku master и heroku open соответственно

Comment: Добавьте содержимое **Procfile**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было создать Procfile. В этом и была проблема